# Android onclickEventListener exception

Tags: java, android

I have the following code

```
public class StartingPoint extends ActionBarActivity {

int counter;
Button add, substract;
TextView display;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_point);

    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    substract = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_subscract);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_display);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter++;
            display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
        }
    });
}
```

Im getting all kinds of exceptions when trying to run it:

```
05-11 21:23:47.604: E/AndroidRuntime(1944): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{l.r.thenewboston/l.r.thenewboston.StartingPoint}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-11 21:23:47.604: E/AndroidRuntime(1944):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
```

What is wrong here ?

The activity starting point layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="l.r.thenewboston.StartingPoint"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

and the fregment_starting_point layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="l.r.thenewboston.StartingPoint$PlaceholderFragment" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_display"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/total_text"
    android:textSize="44sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" 
    android:gravity="center"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_add"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txt_display"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txt_display"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="@string/add_one" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_subscract"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_add"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_add"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txt_display"
    android:text="@string/minus_one"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

```
public PlaceholderFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_starting_point,
            container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

}

Comment: Paste the line of code that the null pointer exception exists on.  Chances are, findViewById isn't finding the view and returning one of your objects null, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Post the `activity_starting_point` layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is that you are trying to access the views in `Fragment Layout` from `Activity`.

This is not possible. . Your `Activity Layout` has only a container to hold the `Fragment`.So the `Activity onCreate` should be to just add the `Fragment`

Move your code in `Activity` `onCreate` to `Fragment`  `onCreateView` like below

You can access the `Buttons` and `TextView` in `Fragment Layout` from `PlaceholderFragment` in `onCreateView` after the `Fragment Layout inflate`

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fregment_starting_point, container,false);

            dd = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        substract = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_subscract);
        display = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_display);

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter++;
                display.setText("Your total is " + counter);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: but the variables dd/substract/display are not in this scope (i have added the static fregment class to my original question)

Comment: Move those inside `PlaceholderFragment`

Comment: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity"

Comment: Are you using `rootView.findViewById`

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
}
```

after

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

and before

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_starting_point);
```

Comment: still getting the same result

Comment: This won't work . How can he add `Fragment` into `R.id.container` before setting the `Layout` to the `Activity`